# Is it possible to pass variable tables through procedures in SQL DEV?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_migrate
(
--v_into_table dba_tables.schema@dbprd%TYPE,
--v_from_table dba_tables.table@dbprd%TYPE,
v_gid IN NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN
    select * INTO fx.T_RX_TXN_PLAN
    FROM fx.T_RX_TXN_PLAN@dbprd
    WHERE gid = v_gid;
    --and schema = v_into_table
    --and table = v_from_table;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

I thought that SELECT * INTO would create a table in the new database from @dbprd. However, the primary issue is just being able to set these as variables and the goal is to EXEC(INTO_Table,FROM_Table,V_GID) to run the above code.

> Error(9,19): PLS-00201: identifier 'fx.T_RX_TXN_PLAN' must be
>   declared  Error(10,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: have a look at `refcursor` or `%rowtype`

Comment: *"I thought that SELECT * INTO would create a table"* - `select into` populates a variable using a query as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html#GUID-6E14E04D-4344-45F3-BE80-979DD26C7A90).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to copy data from table in "another" database into a table that resides in "this" database (regarding database link you used), then it it `INSERT INTO`, not `SELECT INTO`.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_migrate (v_gid in number)
IS
BEGIN
  insert into fx.t_rx_txn_plan (col1, col2, ..., coln)
    select col1, col2, ..., coln
    from fx.t_rx_txn_plan@dbprod
    where gid = v_gid;
END;
```

Last sentence you wrote looks like you'd want to make it *dynamic*, i.e. pass table names and `v_gid` (whatever that might be; looks like all tables that should be involved into this process have it). That isn't a simple task.

If you plan to use `insert into select * from`, that's OK but not for production system. What if someone alters a table and adds (or drops) a column or two? Your procedure will automatically fail. Correct way to do it is to enumerate all columns involved, but that requires fetching data from `user_tab_columns` (or `all_` or `dba_` version of the same), which complicates it even more.

Therefore, if you want to move data from *here* to *there*, why don't you do it using Data Pump Export & Import? Those utilities are designed for such a purpose, and will do the job better than your procedure. At least, I think so.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot! Thanks for responding so quickly. Yes, my goal is to move data from one database to another. I do have a program that does IMPDP/EXPDP however that function seems to take too long to actually transfer the information.

It seems that when I try to compile the code, it can't seem to make a new table in the new database... does this mean I have to make a temp table in order for this to work? Optimally (not sure if this is possible), I would like to change "fx.t_rx_txn_plan, fx.t_rx_txn_plan@dbprod, and v_gid (which is just an id) to be what I want when I do... EXEC(DB1,DB2,'100')

Comment: You're welcome. Well, it is your system, you know it best. If you found out that manually copying data is a better option, go for it.

Comment: If the new table and the existing table that the data [column wise] is coming from are required to match, how would it be possible to do this? Making a temp table?

Comment: In my opinion, you should create the table in the target database, using `create table` command. Then copy data. If you want to dynamically create that table, you'll need to use `execute immediate`, but - doing that over a database link won't work just like that as it is a DDL, DDL commits, and doing that in a distributed transaction from the remote database is not permitted (as far as I can tell). You could try to use a database job, but ... all that leads to a whole lot of complications and will make your life miserable. I'd still go with data pump, if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

This way you should be returning a row. If so, add an `OUT` type parameter to the procedure with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_migrate(
                                         --v_into_table dba_tables.schema@dbprd%TYPE,
                                         --v_from_table dba_tables.table@dbprd%TYPE,
                                         i_gid IN NUMBER,
                                         o_RX_TXN_PLAN OUT fx.T_RX_TXN_PLAN@dbprd%rowtype
                                         ) IS
BEGIN
  SELECT *
    INTO RT_RX_TXN_PLAN
    FROM fx.T_RX_TXN_PLAN@dbprd
   WHERE id = v_gid;
  --and schema = v_into_table
  --and table = v_from_table;

END;
```

and call the procedure such as

```
declare
  v_rx_txn_plan fx.T_RX_TXN_PLAN@dbprd%rowtype;
  v_gid         number:=5345;
begin
  test_migrate(v_gid => v_gid, rt_rx_txn_plan => v_rx_txn_plan);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_rx_txn_plan.col1); 
  dbms_output.put_line(v_rx_txn_plan.col2);              
end;
```

to print out the returning values for some columns of the table. to be able to create a new table from this, not `SELECT * INTO ...` syntax, but

```
  CREATE TABLE T_RX_TXN_PLAN AS
  SELECT *
    INTO RT_RX_TXN_PLAN
    FROM fx.T_RX_TXN_PLAN@dbprd
   WHERE ...
```

is used.

But neither of the cases to issue a `COMMIT` since there's no DML exists within them.

Answer (score 0):

To create a table you must use the `CREATE TABLE` statement, and to use any DDL statement in PL/SQL you have to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_migrate
(
v_gid IN NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE FX.T_RX_TXN_PLAN AS
                         SELECT *
                         FROM fx.T_RX_TXN_PLAN@dbprd
                         WHERE gid = :GID'
      USING IN v_gid;
END;
```

Comment: Hey Bob, I got BEGIN test_migrate("93010"); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 21:
PLS-00201: identifier '93010' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_migrate
(
    v_gid IN NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE fx.T_RX_TXN_PLAN AS
                         SELECT *
                         FROM of.T_RX_TXN_PLAN@dbprd
                         WHERE v_gid = :GID'
      USING IN v_gid;
END;

Is the code I ended up using. Do you know why this error pops up when I try to place the gid as that? Also, how would I be able to change out the two tables (creating and the from table)